# Accessing the owner object from a dynamically declared function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, dynamic, actionscript

A method of one of my classes defines event handler functions dynamically, but I don't know how to access the instance of the class from such a function. Here is an example:

```
public dynamic class SomeClass
{
    public function SomeClass():void
    {
    }

    public function someMethod1():void
    {
    }

    public function someMethod2(eventType:String):void
    {
        var funcName:String = "func" + eventType;
        if (this[funcName] == null)
        {
            this[funcName] = function(event:*):void
                {
                    // this.someMethod1() is not working
                    // "TypeError: Error #1006: someMethod1 is not a function.                       
                };
        }
        this[funcName]("SOME_EVENT_TYPE");
    }
}

// ...

var instance:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
instance.someMethod2();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 1:

As i read your comment there is a more elegant way, as i was influenced by your use of `this` i keep it but using `this` is not a mandatory and in your case just drop the `this` keyword and **call directly your method** it will work :

```
public dynamic class SomeClass
{
    public function someMethod1():void
    {
    }

    public function someMethod2(eventType:String):void
    {
        var funcName:String = "func" + eventType;
        if (this[funcName] == null)
        {
            this[funcName] = function(event:*):void
                {
                    // just call someMethod1() it will be bound to your instance
                    someMethod1(); // here use it as you wish
                    // this.someMethod1() is not working
                    // "TypeError: Error #1006: someMethod1 is not a function.                       
                };
        }
        this.someEventDispatcher.addEventListener(eventType, this[funcName]);
    }
}
```

From what i see you attach the event listener to `someEventDispatcher` so when your event will fire the `this` into your event handler will reference to `someEventDispatcher` and not an instance of `SomeClass`

You can keep a reference of the instance into a variable, so you can use it into your event handler:

```
public dynamic class SomeClass
{
    public function someMethod1():void
    {
    }

    public function someMethod2(eventType:String):void
    {
        var funcName:String = "func" + eventType;
        if (this[funcName] == null)
        {
            var self:SomeClass=this; // here keep the ref to your instance
            this[funcName] = function(event:*):void
                {
                    self.someMethod1(); // here use it as you wish
                    // this.someMethod1() is not working
                    // "TypeError: Error #1006: someMethod1 is not a function.                       
                };
        }
        this.someEventDispatcher.addEventListener(eventType, this[funcName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pleo i have included the simpler way todo it, in short don't use this ;)

Comment: +1 Good Answer, BTW I suggested removing this, Pleo said it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the both, but does it mean that the `self` way is slightly better? (I wouldn't don't mind extra typing with the `self` way after all) Or did you just mean that dynamically declared functions is a bad idea in general? I heard of this too but couldn't find any arguments against this approach..

Comment: I would say better would be to keep functions in an public array rather then using dynamic class. Dynamic classes cause performance issues e.g when you compile to IPA. Better avoid them.

Comment: @san.chez I gotta apologize. It didn't work first time when I tried it, but when Patrick suggested it again, for some reason it did. Sorry =)

Comment: @san.chez You mean handheld Apple devices? This is something my project might target. Anything specific on what problems dynamic classes might cause?

Comment: Just performance. If you want your app to run faster don't use Dynamic and where you can use Final